# masonry images not loading horizontally; only stacking vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I've tried every single instance of css, javascript and jquery initializing that I can think of to get these images to load like a normal masonry pattern but, they keep stacking vertically.

Most of the time the images stacks properly but, when the page finished loading they stack vertically. one by one.

Keep in mind I am using images not the blue boxes. I think the correct way should be in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cxktc/).

Comment: Most of the resources in that Pen point nowhere. You've got to link to the actual scripts somehow.

Comment: fixed. i was doing it late last night, kinda slipped my mind.

Comment: The Pen doesn't seem to have changed. Have you resolved the issue elsewhere?

Comment: I edited the javascript to pull the files in from a cdn. I have yet to resolve this issue.

Comment: The pen hasn't changed for me. Can you make sure it's updated?

Comment: [maybe this gist will work?](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9610610)